# Object could not be found using RealtimeSignalProcessor

Tags: django-haystack, django-cms

I setup all of my projects with the haystack `RealtimeSignalProcessor`;

`HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'haystack.signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor'`

However I frequently see errors coming from searches when objects have been removed from the database;

`Object could not be found in database for SearchResult '<SearchResult: djangocms_text_ckeditor.text (pk=u'357')>'.`

Does this signal processor not run a remove on the index to get rid of old objects?

Comment: Hello Mark, are you using aldryn-search?

Comment: @Paulo hi, yes, we've got a few older projects which have a fork of aldryn-search 0.1.9 to handle app specific results & highlighting. I'm fairly sure that version still had the signal processors though?

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your code, plugins are being registered with the search.
Aldryn Search itself does **not** register plugins with the search, instead it registers the page translations and from there it renders the plugins and stores that as the page translation content but plugins alone are never indexed.

Because plugins are registered directly, you'll hit a lot of issues with realtime indexing because plugins are added and removed under different operations.

ie. When you publish a page, all plugins on the public version of the page are deleted and then recreated from those on the draft version.